# Is it possible to connect zigbee and a GSM modem over the same RX, TX GPIO pins of Pi?

Tags: usb, serial, uart, xbee

I would like to connect a XBee module (Zigbee) and also a GSM modem for voice and SMS. From what I have seen, mostly both uses the Rx, Tx pins of Pi for serial communication. Other option would be to connect it over USB. So, if I connect Zigbee through Rx, Tx pins and use a RS-232 to USB cable to connect the GSM modem, will that be fine...?

The GSM Modem will look like [this](http://researchdesignlab.com/modules/gsm-sim-900.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work.

You can have one serial device connected to the UART (TXD gpio 14 on pin 8, RXD gpio 15 on pin 10) and any needed additional serial devices can be connected via USB serial dongles.